# This facebook page looks different - phishing attempt?

Tags: wifi, phishing, facebook

After logging on to a public wifi, I was redirected to this page appearing to be from facebook, and being done via https:

[image]

which looks markedly different from my normal facebook page

[image]

I understand that if I don't trust a web site, I shouldn't use it.

But what's going on here?

1. The page is legitimate, even though it looks different - maybe it's in mobile mode.
2. The wifi is taking me to a page with a domain that looks like "facebook.com", but is a homograph attack.
3. The wifi is telling me that the page has a domain name of facebook.com, but it's lying.

Comment: That looks like *a different* Facebook page - not yours, but of some "CityLife" group or entity, organized in a different layout from yours. If you can remember the URL you could try and see whether it matches when loaded from a safe connection. Was the wifi by any chance provided by someone related with this CityLife? If so, there are ways to redirect the *initial* connection to one's own page, as a sort of advertisement. Maybe that's all that has happened. Of course you *still* definitely do not want to trust any kindly stranger's wifi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a normal facebook page. They just redirected you to a "Company page", that actually looks quite different than your personal "feed" page.

The wifi actually redirected you to this page:
https://www.facebook.com/CityLifeAUS
and its pretty common for Wifi's to redirect you to their custom "start page" after authentication as a form of advertisement.

and thats why you got logged in automatically too.